# Keynote quits unexpectedly when exporting

Tags: keynote

For the past week or so Keynote has been quitting when I select File > Export To > any option.

It started when I was exporting to the PDF and I was able to use a different export option.  It now quits when I choose any export option.

I am running the beta of Mac OS 12 on a MacBook Pro.  I'm not sure if this is a beta issue or not.

Here is are the crash scripts:

```
Process:               Keynote [3496]
Path:                  /Applications/Keynote.app/Contents/MacOS/Keynote
Identifier:            com.apple.iWork.Keynote
Version:               11.1 (7031.0.102)
Build Info:            Keynote-7031000102000000~2 (1A104)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-09-07 05:59:05.8965 -0700
OS Version:            macOS 12.0 (21A5506j)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     6.0 (19P50506a)
Anonymous UUID:        BB5C86A0-F2FA-5654-E749-7350B0D06A4E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       A21629AF-0100-45EA-B36A-0381AE496091

Time Awake Since Boot: 3600 seconds
Time Since Wake:       138 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007f21cd9184c8
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x00007f21cd9184c8
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [3496]

VM Region Info: 0x7f21cd9184c8 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 16637833319625  Bytes before following region: 768587234104
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      Stack                    700001645000-7000016c7000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=SHM  thread 13
--->  GAP OF 0xfd4bf839000 BYTES
      MALLOC_TINY              7fd4c0f00000-7fd4c1000000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: _isAppearing


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff80420505d objc_msgSend + 29
1   AppKit                              0x7ff807007110 -[NSViewController _viewWillUnhide] + 98
2   AppKit                              0x7ff8076af64a -[NSView _recursiveLostHiddenAncestorBySwitchingWindow:] + 99
3   AppKit                              0x7ff806e6ca01 -[NSView _setSuperview:] + 319
4   AppKit                              0x7ff806e92d96 -[NSView removeFromSuperview] + 140
5   AppKit                              0x7ff806f0c4d4 -[NSView removeFromSuperviewWithoutNeedingDisplay] + 36
6   AppKit                              0x7ff806e98ee7 -[NSView _finalize] + 953
7   AppKit                              0x7ff806e989f6 -[NSView dealloc] + 119
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff80420c19f AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 167
9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff804209160 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 161
10  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff804432a73 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
11  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff804432923 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 445
12  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8044315dd __CFRunLoopRun + 879
13  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff804430bad CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
14  HIToolbox                           0x7ff80d0b48a1 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
15  HIToolbox                           0x7ff80d0b44c8 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 284
16  HIToolbox                           0x7ff80d0b4395 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
17  AppKit                              0x7ff806e4c290 _DPSNextEvent + 886
18  AppKit                              0x7ff806e4a8fc -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1411
19  AppKit                              0x7ff806e3c8e5 -[NSApplication run] + 586
20  AppKit                              0x7ff806e10a40 NSApplicationMain + 816
21  dyld                                   0x10ca3b4d5 start + 421

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.iwork.TSDBrushStrokeLoadQueue
0   CoreGraphics                        0x7ff8096c2a80 aa_render + 2519
1   CoreGraphics                        0x7ff809681164 RIPRenderCoverage + 1620
2   CoreGraphics                        0x7ff8096808ed ripc_Render + 101
3   CoreGraphics                        0x7ff8096c116c ripc_DrawPath + 428
4   CoreGraphics                        0x7ff8099d814d draw_path + 409
5   CoreGraphics                        0x7ff8096c0ed2 CGContextDrawPath + 287
6   TSDrawables                            0x10dfd4d45 0x10db2d000 + 4881733
7   TSDrawables                            0x10dfd5f59 0x10db2d000 + 4886361
8   TSDrawables                            0x10dfd2372 0x10db2d000 + 4871026
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8041c7f6d _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8041bb1d9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8041c1175 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 647
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8041c1c56 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 417
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8041cba11 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 758
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff804368122 _pthread_wqthread + 326
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670af start_wqthread + 15

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff804334c4a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff804334fbb mach_msg + 59
2   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8044330c2 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 319
3   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80443179b __CFRunLoopRun + 1325
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff804430bad CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   AppKit                              0x7ff806fba51c _NSEventThread + 132
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80436b5a8 _pthread_start + 125
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670c3 thread_start + 15

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8043670a0 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00006000024c84b0  rbx: 0x0000600002376700  rcx: 0x00000000000000a4  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00006000024c84b0  rsi: 0x00007ff81ed27dde  rbp: 0x00007ff7b871afd0  rsp: 0x00007ff7b871afb8
   r8: 0x0000000000000010   r9: 0x00007ff81ed59637  r10: 0x00007f21cd9184b0  r11: 0x00007ff81ed27dde
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007ff804205040  r15: 0x00000000000000a4
  rip: 0x00007ff80420505d  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x00007f21cd9184c8
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004 (no mapping for user data read)
Trap Number:     14

Thread 0 instruction stream:
  49 83 c3 10 49 3b 33 75-f1 49 8b 43 08 48 83 f8  I...I;3u.I.C.H..
  00 74 03 4c 31 d0 c3 eb-00 31 c0 c3 66 66 66 66  .t.L1....1..ffff
  66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00-00 00 00 66 66 66 66 66  ff.........fffff
  66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00-00 00 66 0f 1f 44 00 00  f.........f..D..
  48 85 ff 2e 74 72 40 f6-c7 01 2e 75 76 49 ba f8  H...tr@....uvI..
  ff ff ff ff 7f 00 00 4c-23 17 49 89 f3[45]23 5a  .......L#.I..E#Z <==
  18 49 c1 e3 04 4d 03 5a-10 49 3b 33 75 0a 4d 8b  .I...M.Z.I;3u.M.
  5b 08 4d 31 d3 41 ff e3-49 83 3b 01 76 13 49 83  [.M1.A..I.;.v.I.
  c3 10 49 3b 33 75 f1 4d-8b 5b 08 4d 31 d3 41 ff  ..I;3u.M.[.M1.A.
  e3 72 70 4d 8b 5b 08 eb-0a 49 83 3b 01 76 13 49  .rpM.[...I.;.v.I
  83 c3 10 49 3b 33 75 f1-4d 8b 5b 08 4d 31 d3 41  ...I;3u.M.[.M1.A
  ff e3 eb 4f 0f 1f 40 00-31 c0 31 d2 0f 57 c0 0f  ...O..@.1.1..W..

Binary Images:
    0x7ff8041ff000 -     0x7ff804238fff libobjc.A.dylib (*) <00864e0c-0325-380e-bf76-b3fc47f3d5e8> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7ff806e0d000 -     0x7ff807c8ffff com.apple.AppKit (6.9) <410410d9-6583-32f2-a66d-7b56a7c7474b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7ff8043b3000 -     0x7ff8048b4fff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <62277a3b-0caf-3b5a-b561-0e94b889f38e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7ff80d082000 -     0x7ff80d379fff com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1) <1d7674f1-a036-3713-b285-978a1d3ae1af> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
       0x10ca36000 -        0x10ca9dfff dyld (*) <b18442f5-ab91-3945-bd85-304f6d4825c6> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7ff804365000 -     0x7ff804370fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <e812b278-dd28-3795-8163-55ab7100e7f8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7ff80965e000 -     0x7ff809d29fff com.apple.CoreGraphics (2.0) <210be9df-790f-3177-aa04-1483dd40df46> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
       0x10db2d000 -        0x10e440fff com.apple.iWork.TSDrawables (1.0) <a6885a90-0653-38d7-bf50-f03642e443b9> /Applications/Keynote.app/Contents/Frameworks/TSDrawables.framework/Versions/A/TSDrawables
    0x7ff8041b8000 -     0x7ff8041fefff libdispatch.dylib (*) <ec72930b-e75e-3924-b7cc-f7fca26819bc> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7ff804334000 -     0x7ff804364fff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <6ec10bc2-4bcf-3058-8cbe-cfc5164fe41b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.3G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.3G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=2.7G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=2.7G(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               768K        6 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                 3072K        4 
CG image                          16.5M       56 
CG raster data                    86.2M      489 
ColorSync                          244K       28 
CoreAnimation                     23.0M      287 
CoreData Object IDs               4100K        2 
CoreGraphics                        12K        2 
CoreUI image data                 5836K       48 
Foundation                          36K        2 
Image IO                          2624K        3 
Kernel Alloc Once                   76K        2 
MALLOC                           562.7M      138 
MALLOC guard page                   72K       14 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)           1.7G       15         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
SQLite page cache                  512K        8 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       14 
Stack                             14.6M       14 
VM_ALLOCATE                        100K       23 
__CTF                               759        1 
__DATA                            47.1M      615 
__DATA_CONST                      39.8M      420 
__DATA_DIRTY                      1912K      254 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       642.3M       26 
__OBJC_RO                         81.2M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         3040K        2 
__TEXT                           646.9M      623 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
mapped file                      304.9M      225 
shared memory                      796K       21 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              4.5G     3348 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.5G     3348
```

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Keynote?

Comment: You're running a macOS beta and the crash seems to be in AppKit stuff. Please report the crash to Apple via `Feedback`.

Comment: Does it crash on a presentation with is just single slide from a Basic Theme?